# horizantal scrollable textview marquee with pictures android

Tags: android, marquee

I am new to android

I am able to make scrollable marquee textview that contains text only

but the question is how can I insert picture beside each text and keep it scrolling with text

`text1 pic text2 pic text3 pic text4 pic text5 pic text5 pic text6 pic text7 pic`

I can use the same pic and no need to use different pics